# Kibana 7.7.0 Basic version: management tab missing Security panel when started from docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana-7, elasticsearch-x-pack

Context: I want to use XPACK in order to control which user can see which Dasboard only with free version.

I downloaded Kibana 7.7.0 zip from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/windows.html), installed it and I can see Security options to create users/roles. In fact, I created an index, an user and a role and successfully set the index to this role with this installed Elastic/Kibana in my Windows.

The issue happeans only with Elastic/Kibana started from docker. I started Kibana 7.7.0 from a docker and I can't see Security panel under Management page. Googling I found I must use Basic version Instead of Open Source. As far as I can see, the docker-compose bellow is downloading Basic version since there isn't "sso" at the end. Also I must use installers provided by Elastic instad of Apache. Well, as far as I see it is pulling image not related to Apache.

I am not sure if the issue is only with Kibana since I could enable xpack security on Elastic and run elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive inside the elastic docker container. I can log ing in Kibana with Elastic user but I don't see Security tab under Management.

Also, I am getting issue from LogStash trying to connect to ElasticSearch even though I set the logstash_system (see logstash.conf bellow).

You can see that I have enabled xpack.security.enabled=true on ElasticSearch.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:

  zoo1:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 1
      SERVERS: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    command: [start-kafka.sh]
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    links:
      - zoo1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:1:1"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'

  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.7.0
    command: filebeat -e -strict.perms=false
    volumes:
      - "//c/Users/my-comp/docker_folders/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
      - "//c/Users/my-comp/docker_folders/sample-logs:/sample-logs"
    links:
      - kafka1
    depends_on:
      - kafka1

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
     - "//c/Users/my-comp/docker_folders/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.7.0
    volumes:
      - "//c/Users/my-comp/docker_folders/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
    restart: always
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=kibana.localhost
    - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://x.x.x.x:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.7.0
    volumes:
      - "//c/Users/my-comp/docker_folders/logstash.conf:/config-dir/logstash.conf"
    restart: always
    command: logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka1
```

kibana.yml

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "k12345"
```

logstash.conf

```
input{
  kafka{
    codec => "json"
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9092"
    topics => ["app_logs","request_logs"]
    tags => ["myapp"]
  }
}

filter {    
*** not relevant
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://x.x.x.x:9200"]
    index => "%{[fields][topic_name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => "logstash_system" 
    password => "l12345" 
  }
}
```

In case it is worth to mention, LogStash is failling to connect to ElasticSearch with this log and, as you can see from logstash.conf I set up logstash_system (the user created from elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive)

```
logstash_1       | [2020-05-19T20:18:45,559][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-19T20:19:13,815][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
```

So, my straight question is: am I missing some extra configuration in order to enable Security on Kibana? Surrounding questions are: is Kibana/Elastic from docker not the same from zip file? Am I missing some extra configurationin order to allow Logstash to connect to ElasticSearch

*** edited

LogStash is still failling to connect to ElasticSearch after I changed to

logstash.conf

```
...
output {
  elasticsearch {
    #hosts => [ "${ELASTIC_HOST1}", "${ELASTIC_HOST2}", "${ELASTIC_HOST3}" ]
    #hosts => ["http://192.168.99.100:9200"]
    index => "%{[fields][topic_name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://192.168.99.100:9200"]
    xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
    xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: => "l12345" 
  }
}
```

The logs are

```
logstash_1       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
logstash_1       | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:05,095][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:05,120][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.7.0"}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:06,134][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:06,150][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
logstash_1       | Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
logstash_1       | https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,008][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,408][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,506][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
filebeat_1       | 2020-05-20T13:38:53.069Z     INFO    log/harvester.go:297    Harvester started for file: /sample-logs/request-2019-11-17F.log
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,611][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:11,449][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [A-Za-z0-9_-], [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 86, column 7 (byte 2771) after output {\r\n  elasticsearch {\r\n    #hosts => [ \"${ELASTIC_HOST1}\", \"${ELASTIC_HOST2}\", \"${ELASTIC_HOST3}\" ]\r\n\t#hosts => [\"http://192.168.99.100:9200\"]\r\n    index => \"%{[fields][topic_name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\r\n\txpack", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:58:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:66:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:28:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:27:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:181:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:67:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:43:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:342:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

I guess the most relevant part of this log is:

```
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,008][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,408][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash_1       | [2020-05-20T13:39:08,506][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
```

Take a note it is failling with ""Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'" error. I guess that in my particular docker setups it demands to be the Docker Machine IP which in my case is 192.168.99.100. Is there someway to replace elasticsearch by this IP?

Comment: try to disable http level tls.

       - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false

Comment: Thanks, now I can see Security options on Kibana but LogStash remains blocked from conect Elastic. Do you if I did some mistake by using logstash_system user and I should create another with some specific privilege? Logstash keeps printing [ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry code=>403, :url=>"http://192.168.99.100:9200/_bulk"}
... [logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}

Comment: its seems your logstash_system user failed to connect. can you try below config to set password for logstash user and try again. 

xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: logstashpassword

Comment: @m303945 thanks. I am afraid I have to inform it didn't fit it. I added more logs from LogStash above and how I set up xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password

Comment: @m303945 do you know if it is possible to replace "elasticsearch" in http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack' by an IP Address? (see error above related to Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'

Comment: @m303945 please write your first comment as answer so I can pick it up.